# gcov function is not executed but lines are

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcov, lcov

I have been using gcov to check code coverage. I now get a weird result, some functions are listed as not executed but the lines in the function is listed as executed.

lcov output:

```
  13           0 :     f<double>& operator*=(f<double>& lhs, const double& rhs)
  14             :     {
  15           9 :         // Some code...
  16           0 :         return lhs;
  17             :     }
```

gcov output:

```
#####:   13:    f<double>& operator*=(f<double>& lhs, const double& rhs)
    -:   14:    {
    9:   15:        // Some code...
#####:   16:        return lhs;
    -:   17:    }
```

How can the function be listed as NOT executed when the line(s) are? Is this possibly an artifact of GCC's optimization?

EDIT 1:

G++/gcov version: 4.9.2

lcov version: 1.11

EDIT 2:

Comping with `-O2` yields the weird behavior. However, compiling with `-O1` changes the `####` to `9`

Comment: Which version of gcc/gcov are you running? And what command line options do you use for gcov?

Comment: Could this be a result of inlining?

Comment: When I run gcov I get a different file format: `#####:   89:   uint8_t index = dbSize - 1;`  So it is `#####` which indicates not executed followed by the line number, then the text of the line.

Comment: @quamrana g++/gcov 4.9.2 and I used lgov to generate the output.

Comment: Can you run an experiment and define a whole function which is never called to see the difference to above?

Comment: @quamrana If a function is never called I believe the linker will remove it. And thus, the `x :`, where `x` is 0 or 9 in this case, would just not have an `x`.

Comment: Well, you can take the address of a function without calling it. That will keep the linker happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run `gcov` on unoptimised code. This will give you output, perhaps interpreted by lcov, which will assure you that all lines have run.

You can then compile with optimisations on for a release version.

Comment: Well, that will work. I just normally use `-O3` to avoid 500x run time.

Answer (score 2):

The zero simply indicates that `gcov` had no data for the line of code.  That could happen just because there's no convenient way for gcc to *instrument* — modify your program to add the counters (as in the entry to a function).  For instance, if the optimizer removes or combines similar statements in nearby functions, there is nothing to count.

According to the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html):

> The format is

```
 execution_count:line_number:source line text
```

> Additional block information may succeed each line, when requested by command line option. The execution_count is `‘-’` for lines containing no code. Unexecuted lines are marked `‘#####`’ or `‘====’`, depending on whether they are reachable by non-exceptional paths or only exceptional paths such as C++ exception handlers, respectively.

Further reading:

- [What are your tips for interpreting gcov output in order to improve coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140148/what-are-your-tips-for-interpreting-gcov-output-in-order-to-improve-coverage)
- [interpret gcov output to identify basic blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534339/interpret-gcov-output-to-identify-basic-blocks)